# Criando routers para banco de dados múltiplo em Django

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Django em que necessito de vários databases, um para cada usuário do sistema. Para isso defini os databases assim:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'primary': {
        'NAME': 'primary',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'spam',
    },
    'user1': {
        'NAME': 'user1',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'eggs',
    },
    'user2': {
        'NAME': 'user2',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'bacon',
    },
}
```

Em que o banco `user1` e `user2` são réplicas da estrutura de `primary`.

Digamos que eu criei dois superusuarios, com os logins 'superuser1' e 'superuser2'. Como eu defino que quando o 'superuser1' estiver logado os dados sejam alterados no banco 'user1' e quando o 'superuser2' estiver logado sejam alterados os dados no banco 'user2'?

Answer (score 2):

Creio que uma abordagem melhor seria usar [multitenancy](https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2016/understanding-database-multitenancy/). Essa [aplicação](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) torna isso bem simples.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa nativa seria usar o [roteamento de banco de dados](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing), veja o exemplo que a documentação oferece, quando se usa o roteamento de banco de dados o Django oferece uma API para [especificar em qual base você deseja salvar](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save) usando o seguinte código

```
>>> p = Person(name='Fred')
>>> p.save(using='first')  # usa o banco de dados "first"
>>> p.save(using='second') # usa o banco de dados "second"
```

você tambem pode [deletar](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-to-delete-from) escolhendo uma base de dados específica

```
>>> u = User.objects.using('legacy_users').get(username='fred')
>>> u.delete() # will delete from the `legacy_users` database
```